# При попытке поиска в базе данных с помощью Spring высвечивает Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0, с чем связано?

Tags: база-данных, spring, spring-jdbc

При запуске программы, постоянно получаю одну и ту же ошибку. Делал дебаг, но не помогло найти причину.
Код теста

```
@Test
    public void testCfg(){
        GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("classpath:config/embdb.xml");
        ctx.refresh();

        SingerDao singerDao = ctx.getBean(SingerDao.class);

        System.out.println("First name for singer id 1 is: " +
                singerDao.findFirstNameById(1l));

        ctx.close();
    }
```

В конфигурации указано так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А сам метод для поиска:

```
 @Override
    public String findFirstNameById(Long id) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                "select first_name from singer where id = ?",
                new Object[]{id}, String.class);
    }
```

База запускается без проблем, вот её коды:
schema.sql

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists SINGER (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
  , LAST_NAME VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  , BIRTH_DATE DATE
  , UNIQUE UQ_SINGER_1 (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)
  , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists ALBUM (
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
  , SINGER_ID INT NOT NULL
  , TITLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
  , RELEASE_DATE DATE
  , UNIQUE UQ_SINGER_ALBUM_1 (SINGER_ID, TITLE)
  , PRIMARY KEY (ID)
  , CONSTRAINT FK_ALBUM
    FOREIGN KEY (SINGER_ID)
    REFERENCES SINGER (ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

test-data.sql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Cама ошибка выглядит так: org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException: Incorrect result size: expected 1, actual 0

 at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.nullableSingleResult(DataAccessUtils.java:97)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:880)
 at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:901)

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, то проблема каким-то образом свзана с альбомами. Удалил и заработало